# How to paginate data from firebase chaining where method using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, pagination, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to paginate my data from Firebase Database. I am trying to get all posts by a user limiting to 5. I want to use Infinite Scroll in my WebApp (currently writting backend code on Node using Firebase Functions).

Here is the link to the query I wrote:

```js
db.collection('posts')
    .where('user', '==', user)
    .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    .startAfter(page)
    .limit(5).get()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

error msg:

```
FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: (which provides a link)
```

edit: found the solution. On clicking the link it takes me to Firebase console for creating a composite key
[screenshot of firebase console window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKRAi.png)

Comment: So what problem do you exactly have? What doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, should have added the error message. I have found the solution, thank you for your concern :)

Comment: Your question has been reopened; you should put the answer in the Answer box below and not as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution. On clicking the link it takes me to Firebase console for creating a composite key
[screenshot of firebase console window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKRAi.png)